# solving minimum through derivatives

Tags: calculus

The original equation which we need to find the derivative for is 
$\frac{\sqrt{4+(3-x)^2}}{.3} + \frac{x}{.7}$
. I found the derivative to be 
$\frac{x-3}{.3\sqrt{x^2-6x+13}} + \frac{1}{.7}$. Once I solved this I found the answer to be 
$.4x^2 - 2.4x + 3.24$. This gives you right zero, however it goes from positive to negative and has 2 zeros. The derivative I first found before simplifying goes from negative to positive. What changed when I simplified the derivative to cause this, and why does my simplified derivative give the right zero.

Answer (score 1):

The two expressions you wrote down: $\frac{x-3}{.3\sqrt{x^2-6x+13}}+\frac{1}{.7}$ and $.4x^2-2.4x+3.24$ definitely don't describe the same function (look at a graph if you don't believe me). I suspect that what you actually did was set the original expression to zero: $$\frac{x-3}{.3\sqrt{x^2-6x+13}}+\frac{1}{.7} = 0$$ and you tried to solve for $x$. After some manipulation you found that the original expression is equal to zero exactly when the second expression is equal to zero: $$\frac{x-3}{.3\sqrt{x^2-6x+13}}+\frac{1}{.7} = 0 \iff .4x^2-2.4x+3.24 = 0.$$ This does NOT imply that the two expressions are equivalent.